# Initial Page blank until Page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Basically when I hit the first page and click on the button, it should display the first 2 dynamic posts. Unfortunately no post is displayed until I hit the refresh button on my browser before the first 2 posts appears.

I have spent hours trying to figure out what I am missing in this code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var data = $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/?json=recentstories", function(data) {

    var $postsList = $('#postlist'),
        $loadMore = $postsList.parent().find('.load-more'),
        currentPage = 0,
        postsPerPage = 2;
    var showMorePosts = function () {
        var offset = currentPage * postsPerPage,
        posts = data.posts.slice(offset, offset + postsPerPage);
        $.each(posts, function ( i, val ) {

        $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>').appendTo($postsList);

           });
            if( posts.length !== postsPerPage ) {
            $loadMore.hide();
        }
       currentPage++;
       $postsList.listview('refresh');
        };
    $postsList.listview();
    showMorePosts();
    $loadMore.on('click', showMorePosts);
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Page: home -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="d" data-title="My Devotion">
        <div data-role="listview">
            <a href="#devotion" id="devotionclick" data-role="button">Daily Devotional Messages</a>
        </div><!-- links -->
    </div><!-- page -->

<!-- Page: Daily Devotional Messages -->
    <div id="devotion" data-role="page" data-title="My Devotion">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"> <h2>Daily Devotional Messages</h2></div><!-- header -->
        <ul data-theme="d" id="postlist"> </ul><!-- content -->
        <div class="load-more">Load More Posts...</div> 
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Also seeing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery1101005234554712660611' of undefined
```

Comment: On which line of your code are you seeing the error?

Comment: caused by "$postsList.listview();"

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are not adding callback parameter "callback=?" to your json request url, It shouldnt matter if your code is from the same server.

also, the "#postlist" is empty, it doesnt contain any li elements,
the error is caused when  "$postsList.listview();" is called.
maybe because your ul is empty.

You can inspect element the "#postlist" to find it empty

Comment: Technically Yes, "#postlist" would be empty. My intention was for it to first show the two posts before it then Loads new once on click more